# Jenkins rewrites config.xml

Tags: windows, jenkins, config

I have installed jenkins using the .msi but get an java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException when trying to load.

I have followed the advice to change the useSecurity to false, and remove authorizationStrategy and securityRealm from the config.xml.

When I restart Jenkins on the command line, it rewrites the config.xml to its original state, and the error remains.

Any ideas how to solve this?

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\secrets\hudson.util.Secret
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at jenkins.security.DefaultConfidentialStore.store(DefaultConfidentialStore.java:79)
at jenkins.security.ConfidentialKey.store(ConfidentialKey.java:51)
at jenkins.security.CryptoConfidentialKey.getKey(CryptoConfidentialKey.java:44)
Caused: java.lang.Error: Failed to load the key: hudson.util.Secret
at jenkins.security.CryptoConfidentialKey.getKey(CryptoConfidentialKey.java:53)
at jenkins.security.CryptoConfidentialKey.decrypt(CryptoConfidentialKey.java:134)
at hudson.util.HistoricalSecrets.decrypt(HistoricalSecrets.java:49)
at hudson.util.Secret.decrypt(Secret.java:207)
at hudson.util.Secret.fromString(Secret.java:239)
at jenkins.security.ApiTokenProperty.<init>(ApiTokenProperty.java:86)
at jenkins.security.ApiTokenProperty$DescriptorImpl.newInstance(ApiTokenProperty.java:179)
at jenkins.security.ApiTokenProperty$DescriptorImpl.newInstance(ApiTokenProperty.java:164)
at hudson.model.User.load(User.java:205)
at hudson.model.User.<init>(User.java:157)
at hudson.model.User.getOrCreate(User.java:470)
at hudson.model.User.getById(User.java:541)
at hudson.security.HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm.createAccount(HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm.java:403)
at jenkins.install.SetupWizard.init(SetupWizard.java:109)
at jenkins.install.InstallState$3.initializeState(InstallState.java:105)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins.setInstallState(Jenkins.java:1062)
at jenkins.install.InstallUtil.proceedToNextStateFrom(InstallUtil.java:96)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:952)
at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:86)
at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:82)
at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:235)
Caused: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:249)
```

Comment: `java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\secrets\hudson.util.Secret` means you don't have permission to edit file. Can you try start Jenkins by Administrator?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be an IT policy of the company I am working for that was stopping me from creating .secret files.

I have to ask for a security exception to be able to install and run Jenkins. So you were right Tuan, it was a permission issue.

Thank you.